# Is it possible to adjust column width per row in confluence wiki?

Tags: confluence

Is it possible to have different number of columns in different rows but still keep the width of the row flush with each other.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to have a different number of columns per row, confluence just makes an empty column for the extra space if you try. Why do you need a table like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using Confluence v4.x

I would use the [Confluence Source Editor](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.editor.confluence-source-editor;jsessionid=1quxblracdw0q1rrts9qlzlnck) plugin which will enable you to take a look at the new xhtml source format. From there, you can add a colspan attribute on the row tag to control the columns in that row.

I have used a similar approach to get a table with 2 rows having 1 column and 2 columns each.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to the best of my recollection, you just need to fill the columns with empties. If you could provide some code I could perhaps assist better.